# HDFStore error 'correct atom type -> [dtype->uint64'

Tags: pandas, pytables

using read_hdf for first time love it want to use it to combine a bunch of smaller *.h5 into one big file.  plan on calling append() of a HDFStore.  later will add chunking to conserve memory.

Example table looks like this

Int64Index: 220189 entries, 0 to 220188
Data columns (total 16 columns):
ID                    220189  non-null values
duration              220189  non-null values
epochNanos            220189  non-null values
Tag                   220189  non-null values
dtypes: object(1), uint64(3)

code:

```
import pandas as pd
print pd.__version__  # I am running 0.11.0
dest_h5f = pd.HDFStore('c:\\t3_combo.h5',complevel=9)
df = pd.read_hdf('\\t3\\t3_20130319.h5', 't3', mode = 'r')
print df
dest_h5f.append(tbl, df, data_columns=True)
dest_h5f.close()
```

Problem: the append traps this exception
Exception: cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->uint64,items->Index([InstrumentID], dtype=object)] 'module' object has no attribute 'Uint64Col'

this feels like a problem with some version of pytables or numpy
pytables = v 2.4.0    numpy = v 1.6.2

Comment: this was just fixed in master: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3494, can you give a try with that? (will also be in the 0.11.1 release), should be soon

Comment: also note that uint64 cannot be used in indicies (though as a column shouldn't be a problem)

Comment: Ok running on the patched version.   How would I force it to use a supported dtype index.   All my fields are uint64 and strings. I tried a df = df.reset_index(drop = True)  but I still seem to have    NotImplementedError: indexing 64-bit unsigned integer columns is not supported yet, sorry

Comment: is ther a reason u really need uint64? and not int64? uint64 don't place nice with the indices ( unrelated to HDFStore)

Comment: I am already going back to the source file origins...  (I did not write that.)  to see if it is a simple thing to swap it out.  looks like this  final_df.to_records().astype([('epochNanos_cmi', 'i8'),...   I would expect the i8 to be a singed 64bit int but for some reason it is a uint64 when I pull it into pandas...

Comment: there are huge numbers like the number of nanos since 1970-1-1

Comment: see my answer as to why you should use int64, or datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 0):

We normally represent epcoch seconds as `int64` and use `datetime64[ns]`. Try using `datetime64[ns]`, will make your life easier. In any event nanoseconds since 1970 is well within the range of in64 anyhow. (and uint64 only buy you 2x this range). So no real advantage to using unsigned ints.

We use int64 because the min value (-9223372036854775807) is used to represent `NaT` or an integer marker for Not a Time

```
In [11]: (Series([Timestamp('20130501')])-
                Series([Timestamp('19700101')]))[0].astype('int64')
Out[11]: 1367366400000000000

In [12]: np.iinfo('int64').max
Out[12]: 9223372036854775807
```

You can then represent time form about the year 1677 till 2264 at the nanosecond level